# MS Access alter multiple columns

Tags: ms-access, alter-table

I have an ODBC linked table from JDE/AS400 that I'm bringing into MS Access 2010. The table has four fields with data types of decimal that I need to convert to double data types once I've written them to a temp table. Is there not a way to have four alter table/column statements in one query?

In case anyone is wondering, the data stored in these fields is price and cost, but they are stored in the ODBC table as decimal values of 15 with 0 trailing decimals and I have to divide two by 10,000 and one by 100,000 to get the decimal points in the right position to represent the true price/cost For example, 3558767 in the price field is actually a price of 355.8767 or 355.88 rounded). When I bring the same data into Access and divide by 10000, I get 355.00. I need the correct cents value. The only way I've been able to do this in the past is to write an alter table/alter column query to change the data type to double before performing the division.

Since I have four of these fields, I'd like to alter or modify all four at once. Any ideas?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is extremely confusing. What are the data types in Access? What exactly are you trying to do?  Also, if you're storing prices, you probably don't want to use `Double` since it's a floating point.

Comment: Sorry Bobby, I know it is confusing. Working JD Edwards files always is it seems. The data types in Access are coming over exactly as they are stored in the linked table, which is a decimal data type, 15 numbers in length. What data type do you suggest for this? I've tried currency, but since I first have to divide these amounts since the AS400/JDE linked table is storing them as decimal w/o decimal points in them, I can't simply convert them to currency w/o first dividing them to get the decimal where it belongs.

Comment: I went ahead and wrote out the four alter table queries, but if someone can tell me a way outside of VBA to write a simple query that will alter more than one column in the same table in a single query in MS Access, I'd be appreciative. Thx. Tim

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way in Access (or ANSI-compliant SQL, as far as I'm aware) to alter multiple columns at the same time; you would have to either:

- run four separate alter scripts, or ...
- create a new temporary table, move all the data into the temporary table, drop the main table, then rename the temporary

It's really a wash in this case, since you'll be running four scripts either way.

Comment: Thanks Bobby. That's what I'd found when searching elsewhere, but thought a post to see if I was missing something wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, Access SQL won't allow you to alter more than one column with a single SQL statement.  However, there is something confusing about the background information in your question.

```
SELECT decimal_field/10^4 AS my_quotient
FROM tblFoo;
```

`decimal_field` is Decimal type with precision = 15 and scale = 0.

When I store `3558767` to `decimal_field` and run that query, Access 2007 gives me `355.8767` as `my_quotient`.  And that's the result I understood you want but aren't getting.

If you can sort that out perhaps you don't need to alter any column.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I did try doing the division on the decimal_field in the first query that pulls the data from the linked table and it keeps rounding it down. Not sure why that is. I'll give it another shot and see if I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: OK, sounds like you've already been down the route I had in mind.  I don't understand why it would discard the decimal places --- maybe that's an aberration with that particular ODBC driver.